# How to convert HTML file into PDF and save it in projects media folder using django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I have to create a dynamic pdf from html file in this pdf i am passing some keywords as well as barcode is also generated, basically this pdf is a ticket of an event.

So i have to save this pdf in project's media foleder so that user can download it from his/her account

I have successfully created pdf from  html file, i have used code on stackoverflow and its working fine but the problem is that it's opening in  tab, i have to save it in directory.

Here is my code

```
def testing_pdf(request):

image = treepoem.generate_barcode(
    barcode_type='azteccode',
    data='00100111001000000101001101111000010100111100101000000110',
    options={'layers':5} 
)
image.save(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/barcodes/barcode.png')
template = get_template('home/pdf-template/index.html')
context_dict = { 'name':'Testing','event': 'testing', 'barcode':image}
context = Context(context_dict)
html  = template.render(context)

result = StringIO.StringIO()
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
if not pdf.err:
    response = HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return response
return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

What should i do in my this code so that it can be saved into my project's  media directory.

Comment: can we have one question at a time please

Comment: Ok how can i save it in project's directory ?

Comment: no not in the comments. YOu edit this question and make it more specific. When you get an answer to that question, post a new one with your next question.

Comment: Please check edit